# How to return a Stream in Dart without looping through it

Tags: dart, stream, yield

I have a Stream in my code, which I've done some modifications / transformations to. I'd like to return that Stream as the result of my function.

This code works:

```
Stream<int> returnStream2() async* {
  var list = <int>[1,2,3];
  var result = Stream<int>.fromIterable(list);
  await for( var i in result ) {
    yield i;
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this simpler and more readable version work?

```
Stream<int> returnStream1() async* {
  var list = <int>[1,2,3];
  var result = Stream<int>.fromIterable(list);
  return result;
}
```

I get an error message "Can't return a value from a generator function (using the 'async*' modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `yield*` as you already discovered, or just don't make the function an `async*` function. If this stream is the only thing you yield, you can just do:

```dart
Stream<int> returnStream1() {
  var list = <int>[1,2,3];
  var result = Stream<int>.fromIterable(list);
  return result;
}
```

If you do other things, then `yield* stream;` or `await for (var event in stream) yield event;` are both options (they differ in how they handle error events from the stream, but for plain data events the two should be equivalent).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the yield* keyword, which solves my problem:

```
Stream<int> returnStream1() async* {
  var list = <int>[1,2,3];
  var result = Stream<int>.fromIterable(list);
  yield* result;
}
```